# 422 error 'unprocessable entity' when calling API from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension that aims to send information (url, title etc.) from the current page the user is on to a REST API with a Rails backend. The API call works when I test it with Postman but when I send the data through my extension, I receive the `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` error.

This file listens for the click in my extension:

```js
function listenClick() {
  const button = document.getElementById('send-data');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'scripts/send-data.js'
    });
  })
}

listenClick();
```

This is the `send-data.js` file:

```
function fetchData() {
  title = document.querySelector('title').innerText;
  const url = window.location.href;

  return {
    title: title,
    url: url
  }
}

function sendData(data){
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bookmarks';
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-User-Email": "test@mail.com",
      "X-User-Token": "asdfkljIOJDHalsdfkla"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "title": `${data.title}`,
      "url": `${data.url}`,
    })
  })
}

sendData(fetchData());
```

The error occurs on the line starting with `'X-User-Email'`. I am using the `'simple_token_authentication'` gem to authenticate users, which uses these headers.

Could someone help me to see what I'm missing?

Comment: Modern Chrome disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts, see [CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches). Perform the request in the background script.

Comment: Check rails log. Does the request reach to rails application? `422 error is coming from rails application` or `Chrome disallows cross-origin requests`.
If  `422 error is coming from rails application`: compare request `params`, and share both request log here. So, we can help you.

Comment: I checked the rails logs and the problem actually was with my ruby code. I was assigning the bookmark to a collection that didn't exist for that specific user. Thank you for the hint @mahfuz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that the problem was with my ruby code and not with the js.file quoted above. Checking the rails logs helped me realize that.

Comment: What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content type of the header. **header:{ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;application/json' }**

Comment: Could you please add an explanation ?